# how to use the context in the tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec2

please help write tests with context.

model Album:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum:  50, minimum: 3 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum:  600, minimum: 10 }
end
```

I wrote tests for model Album:

```
describe Album do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.create(:album)).to be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without title" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:album, title: nil)).not_to be_valid
  end  

  it "is invalid with duplicate title" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:album, title: 'qwerty')
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:album, title: 'qwerty')).not_to be_valid
  end 

  it "is valid with different title" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:album, title: 'zxcvbn')
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:album, title: 'asdfgh')).to be_valid
  end        
end
```

these tests worked OK. but i need use context:

```
describe Album do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.create(:album)).to be_valid
  end

  describe '#title' do
    context "invalid" do
      it "is invalid without title" do
        expect(FactoryGirl.build(:album, title: nil)).not_to be_valid
      end  

      it "is invalid with long title" do
        expect(FactoryGirl.build(:album, title: 'If you liked my series on practical advice for adding reliable tests to your Rails apps, check out the expanded ebook version. Lots of additional, exclusive content and a complete sample Rails application.')).not_to be_valid
      end        

      it "is invalid with duplicate title" do
        FactoryGirl.create(:album, title: 'qwerty')
        expect(FactoryGirl.build(:album, title: 'qwerty')).not_to be_valid
      end       
    end

    context "valid" do
      it "is valid with title" do
        expect(FactoryGirl.build(:album, title: 'good title')).not_to be_valid
      end  

      it "is valid with different title" do
        FactoryGirl.create(:album, title: 'zxcvbn')
        expect(FactoryGirl.build(:album, title: 'asdfgh')).to be_valid
      end  
    end
  end      
end
```

but these tests is not DRY. please help write the test with context again.

ps:
good practices that I tried to use:

1. checking limiting cases (a very small value, very great value,
   average value)
2. use contexts for the organization code
3. each test should be in a separate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests using `context` looks okay. But, you can write better tests using `context` by following the best practices. See [better specs](http://betterspecs.org/#contexts) guidelines to see how to write better RSpec tests.

Also, see the following classic example of using `context` from the [The RSpec Style Guide](https://github.com/howaboutwe/rspec-style-guide)

```
# A classic example for use of contexts in a controller spec is creation or update when the object saves successfully or not.

describe ArticlesController do
  let(:article) { mock_model(Article) }

  describe 'POST create' do
    before { Article.stub(:new).and_return(article) }

    it 'creates a new article with the given attributes' do
      Article.should_receive(:new).with(title: 'The New Article Title').and_return(article)
      post :create, article: { title: 'The New Article Title' }
    end

    it 'saves the article' do
      article.should_receive(:save)
      post :create
    end

    context 'when the article saves successfully' do
      before { article.stub(:save).and_return(true) }

      it 'sets a flash[:notice] message' do
        post :create
        flash[:notice].should eq('The article was saved successfully.')
      end

      it 'redirects to the Articles index' do
        post :create
        response.should redirect_to(action: 'index')
      end
    end

    context 'when the article fails to save' do
      before { article.stub(:save).and_return(false) }

      it 'assigns @article' do
        post :create
        assigns[:article].should be_eql(article)
      end

      it 're-renders the "new" template' do
        post :create
        response.should render_template('new')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: but this example for controller

Comment: Yes, but this shows you how to properly use `context` in your RSpec tests. I would recommend you to look at this: http://betterspecs.org/#contexts
This will help you write better spec tests with proper contexts.